# Automaticly logout user from FOS user bundle symfony 2.8.4

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, fosuserbundle

How do I loggout user automaticly after X time?
for now even the user come back after 2 days to his computer the app still bypass the login page and give him the authorization

Answer (score 1):

Need to look at session idle time if you want it so that it expires after a certain time period.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#session-idle-time-keep-alive

You need to modify your config.yml file

```
#app/config/config.yml
session:
    // set your values here
    cookie_lifetime: 86400  
    gc_maxlifetime: 18000
```

Comment: Hi @user3130641 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/237701) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the cookie expiry.
Have a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html and search for `cookie_lifetime`. It sounds like you might want to set it to `0` so that it expires once the user closes their browser tab.